# Python Spiderplot: reduce y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, radar-chart

I am looking for ways to reduce the intervals of y-axis to 0, 20, 40, 60, 80, & 100

My graph currently looks like this:

[image]

This is the code I'm using:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

df = pd.DataFrame({'Day': ['1.Monday', '2.Tuesday', '3.Wednesday', '4.Thursday', '5.Friday'],
                  'Percentage': [71, 35, 27, 63, 91]})


ax = sp.spiderplot(x="Day", y='Percentage',  legend= False,
               data=df, palette="husl", rref=0)
ax.set_rlim([0,100])
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))   

# plt.title(state, fontsize=20)
plt.xticks(rotation=0)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=15)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=20)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used this library before, but you can add the following code to support it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import spiderplot as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

df = pd.DataFrame({'Day': ['1.Monday', '2.Tuesday', '3.Wednesday', '4.Thursday', '5.Friday'],
                  'Percentage': [71, 35, 27, 63, 91]})


ax = sp.spiderplot(x="Day", y='Percentage',  legend= False,
               data=df, palette="husl", rref=0)
ax.set_rlim([0,100])
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))   

# plt.title(state, fontsize=20)
plt.xticks(rotation=0)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,100,20)) #update
ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=15)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=20)
plt.show()
```

[image]